# Current state of pythonPort in Boost.Build.V2

Tags: python, bjam, boost-build

I'm currently using bjam boost.build as my preference C++ building tool. But using bjam programming language is sometimes quite hard and non-intuitive to me.

Henceforth I'm waiting with impatience to boost.build.V2 Milestone 15, "[PythonPort](https://trac.lvk.cs.msu.su/boost.build/wiki/PythonPort)"

But even now with Boost.build Milestone 12, when I look in boost-build directories I see python files matching most jams.

Henceforth I wonder what are those files for and if there is a way to use python extensions in my bjam from the current boost.build version ?

Comment: Feel free to ignore this question - but I'm actually curious. If bjam is difficult to use, what keeps you soldiering on using it? This is a bit of a derailment from your question I'm sure but.. I'm honestly curious.

Comment: Really bjam is the simplest makefile system I ever used. You define rules like "exe target : dependencies ;", or "unittest target : dependencies ;" I do not have to deal with OS details at all, the type of rule deals with that. bjam also keeps things tidy (all in one directory) and does not pollute repositories with any file. Most of what I need is already available and I'm mostly happy with it. The only drawback is that extending it is really hard because of the strange syntax used to write new functions (because that's what really are target rules). If only I could do that using python...

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response on this.

Comment: I'm also keen to see this reach fruition however it does look as if the project stalled some time ago. A shame really, because I'm really starting to like the concepts behind bjam/b2/Boost.Build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a build tool written in Python, have a look at [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), especially the [user guide](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html). Its configuration (SConstruct) files are actually Python scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try. But really I'm not willing to renounce to every other nice features of bjam just for getting python extension now instead of waiting a few more months.